# How do I show the markdown text in preview in kanboard?

Tags: windows-10

[image: This is what I see]

[image: This is what I want to see]

I want to see test123 outside in first figure of board as well. How do I do it?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? What are the details of this Kanboard setup? Have you gone through Kanboard's documents on this?

Comment: Off-topic here in the 1st place as it's a self-hosted web app.